# Nginx inside docker container can't talk to other containers (running jenkins)

Tags: nginx, docker

I'm trying to set up a nginx proxy inside docker that will listen for web traffic and then based on virtualhosts forward traffic to differerat jenkins instances also running inside docker containers. To orchestrate this I use docker-compose.

I have managed to:

- Start up jenkins instances and talk to them directly
- Start nginx and configure it to act as a proxy for a webserver running on another host

But when I try to let the nginx server route the traffic inside docker I cant get it to work, just getting 502-Bag Gateway errors and the folowing in the nginx logs:

```
[error] 6#6: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "localhost:8080"
```

Relevant parts of my docker-compose.yml:

```
httpd:
  build: httpd
  ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  links:
      - "server_jenkins"
      - "clients_jenkins"
  restart: always

server_jenkins:
  image: jenkins
  ports:
      - "8081:8080"
  restart: always

clients_jenkins:
  image: jenkins
  ports:
      - "8082:8080"
  restart: always
```

The httpd/Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM nginx
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx
COPY config /etc/nginx/
```

And relevant parts of nginx.conf looks like this (only proxying one jenkins instance):

```
http {
    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name server.build.example.com;
        root /tmp;

        location / {
            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8081;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name clients.build.example.com;
        root /tmp;

        location / {
            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8082;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried the following variants of the first proxy_pass url (and some other that I don't remember):

- http://server_jenkins:8081
- http://172.18.0.3:8081  (ip-number assigned to the server_jenkins when 
  running with --x-networking)

When running with --x-networking I changed the link statements to container_name in docker-compose.yml

Versions:

- docker: 1.9.1, build a34a1d5
- docker-compose: 1.5.2, build 7240ff3
- OS: Debian 8 (running inside Virtualbox)

Comment: Please provide clear error messages. "[...] I cant get it to work.[...]" isn't sufficient at all.

Comment: Well I get 502-Bad Gateway from the nginx server when I go to localhost:8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.
I was confused over how portmapping works.

The working config:
docker-compose.yml:

```
httpd:
  build: httpd
  ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  links:
      - "server_jenkins"
      - "clients_jenkins"
  restart: always

server_jenkins:
  image: jenkins
  restart: always

clients_jenkins:
  image: jenkins
  restart: always
```

nginx.conf:

```
http {
    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name server.build.example.com;
        root /tmp;

        location / {
            proxy_pass   http://server_jenkins:8080;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name clients.build.example.com;
        root /tmp;

        location / {
            proxy_pass   http://client_jenkins:8080;
        }
    }
}
```

Ie. There are no need for mapping the ports.

Comment: no need for an upstream{} block?

Comment: @gdbj I thought the same thing, too.  One needs an upstream block to define the backends before one can refer to said backends.  Some config is missing here.

Answer (score 0):

I am deleting my previous answer as I was answering something completely different.
I found your problem, its the `http://127.0.0.1` and ports which is wrong, `127.0.0.1` inside nginx's conf means the `httpd` container itself in this case not the host.

If you re-define that to `server_jenkins` and `clients_jenkins` and also suffix the `8080` port for both of those, then it should work.

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name server.build.example.com;
    root /tmp;

    location / {
        proxy_pass   http://server_jenkins:8080;
    }
}
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name clients.build.example.com;
    root /tmp;

    location / {
        proxy_pass   http://clients_jenkins:8080;
    }
}
```

Also, I noticed that the http directive causes errors, but as you mentioned the file you have provided can be just a snippet.

Comment: Somewhat, the actual server configs will bee more complex (I'll update the  orig-post)